# How to make the new input value replace the old automatically and immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `input`.
I press a number, lets say `1`. Now when I press `2`, I want the `2` to replace the `1`.

I have tried this so far:

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 $(this).val(value[value.length-1]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
```

As you can see, it works but very silly. How to make the `2` immediately replace the `1` without any delay?
Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `input` event instead of `keydown`, it fires immediately when the field content changes.

```js
$("input").on('input', function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 $(this).val(value[value.length-1]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
```

Comment: It works fine, but I wonder what is the difference between `on('input')` and `input()`?

Comment: jQuery has shortcuts for several events, https://api.jquery.com/category/events/ (but I don’t see `.input()` there), `.on` is a general helper that can be used to subscribe for all types of events, or even multiple at once.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you were looking for? Instead of getting value and replacing last one, just empty the input every time user types something

```js
$("input").keydown(function(){
  $(this).val('');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
```